# Is it possible to make a mesh symmetrical without mirror modifier?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I created a base mesh to sculpt upon using a mirror modifier, but then applied the mirror before adding a multires to sculpt with. During sculpting I went into edit mode and made some changes to the base mesh, forgetting that my alterations were not being mirrored. I tried re-adding the mirror, but it can't be moved above the multires. I've also tried manually correcting the problem, but it's still not how it should be. Is there a way I can make my base mesh symmetrical again, or do I just have to live with my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes.

It *is* possible to make a mesh symmetrical without a Mirror Modifier.

Simply set your Pivot Point to be your 3D Cursor, place the 3D Cursor at the center of symmetry, duplicate the geometry to be mirrored (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>), and scale (<kbd>S</kbd>) -1 on the axis of symmetry (in this case the X axis <kbd>X</kbd>).

You can set the Pivot Point to the 3D Cursor here:

[image: Set Pivot Point to 3D Cursor]

Take this example of half a monkey:

[image: Suzanne being mirrored manually within Edit Mode using duplication and scaling -1 along the X axis]

Finally, pressing <kbd>W</kbd> and choosing Remove Doubles can get rid of overlapping vertices and weld the mesh halves together.

You'll want to Recalculate Normals after doing this (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>) because the face normals get flipped inside-out in the scaling process.